# Tooling API and Scheduled Batch Apex - How to access

Tags: batch, security, scheduled-apex, tooling-api, security-review

Without storing a users credentials to salesforce how can one access the tooling API during a daily scheduled batch?

Currently we are storing the users username and password in encrypted fields but this is a security no no. All examples I have seen require a session ID but this is unavailable during batch execution. Some examples pass in a session ID but require the batch to be scheduled via code.

Ideally I need a way to simply run the batch and query the tooling API during batch execution without having to violate security requirements by storing usernames and passwords...

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's no problem so long as it's encrypted, because anyone that could see the password can login as the user without their consent anyways. That said, I'd probably use refresh tokens so that you can regenerate access tokens while in a batch process. You also don't need to store their password, and you can limit the tokens scope to reduce data exposure.

Comment: @sfdcfox: Thats what I thought as well. I even thought of using a hash encryption using a hash key stored in a private custom setting then encrypting the password with that so even the admin could not get the password with view encrypted, but salesforce security review is not having it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't get a users context in a scheduled batch without authenticating them (had this same issue trying to run the first iteration of the analytics API in a scheduled job).

You could however implement OAuth with the Tooling API so that the user's refresh token is used for access. That you can store as if working with any 3rd party system.

Alternatively you could store the user credentials in encrypted fields. Personally I prefer the OAuth route as it is the designed route for such API interactions.

Comment: I was informed by salesforce ISV team that we will not pass security review if we store either the username and password or the refresh token. I guess I am out of luck at this point....Waiting on office hours to confirm the review requirements as I may have been told wrong as well.

Comment: This is from salesforce's own documentation on OAuth so you should be okay "The refresh token may have an indefinite lifetime, persisting for an admin-configured interval or until explicitly revoked by the end-user. The client application can store the refresh token, using it to periodically obtain fresh access tokens, but should be careful to protect it against unauthorized access, since, like a password, it can be repeatedly used to gain access to the resource server." See https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com